# Java swing table focus change

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to change the focus of java swing table first cell to next when enter key pressed.
Can we change the focus of first cell to a specific cell when an 
event occured.I tried setfocus but failed.Any help please

My table having three coloumns and one row as default.When the user enter values to
(0,0) cell, and then press enter it should move the focus and editor to next cell(i e, 0,1).
When reached 3rd coloumn, after types values to the coloumn and pressed enter key, it should add a new row to the table.And move the focus and editor to first cell of created row.It should repeat the same procedure along.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/) of your best effort to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to change the focus of java swing table first cell to next when enter key pressed

This is the default behaviour for the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

You can share this `Action` with the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key by changing the `Key Bindings` of the table by using:

```
KeyStroke tab = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("TAB");
KeyStroke enter = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER");
InputMap im = table.getInputMap(JTable.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
im.put(enter, im.get(tab));
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more information.

Comment: how can I get focus to specific cell ?

Comment: What do you mean "specific cell"? What if you are on row 1 or row 2 or row 3? What cell do you want to go to? Update you question with a proper requirement. Your requirement says you want to go to the next cell.